# Advice on ASP.NET MVC to Java migration?

Tags: java, asp.net-mvc, jsf, struts2

I'm an ASP.NET developer trying to learn Java web dev. I would like to migrate a small ASP.NET MVC site to Java.  I have the ASP.NET code and the SQL Server database.  I'm comfortable with Netbeans and Eclipse.  I know the basics of servlets and JSPs.  I'm wondering whether it would make sense to use a web framework instead of using JSP/servlets directly.

I'm stuck at what Java web framework to use.  I would prefer a framework that's MVC based, can generate a data layer quickly based on an existing database schema and has an easy learning curve.  I've peeked at Struts2 and JSF. Both seem a bit complicated but if I spend more time on it, perhaps they be more approachable...?

Are there other frameworks I should explore?  Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

I'm kinda Spring Framework fan, so I would recommend Spring MVC. I warn you - it isnt easy.   You could reuse JSP as view layer, and switch later to Freemarker/Velocity. And maybe some Hibernate later. There is cool plugin pack for Eclipse from Spring, called Spring Tool Suite - makes development easier. And page with examples: http://www.springbyexample.org/ :)